# Can anyone tell me what make or brand this frame is?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I can't figure out who made this or what brand maker it is. It has the serial number and on top of it it has a different number.

> G0Q230-2
>
> Wbdo26l0431p

[image]

Comment: Better pictures would increase the chances of recognizing features of the frame that would help identify the maker. This link will explain what to take pictures of: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1340/41662

Answer (score 1):

Sorry  serial numbers are only helpful if you already know the manufacturer AND they used some kind of system, AND kept records AND EITHER those records are available for searching, OR someone has figured+published the encoding system.

As it stands, I see a BMX frame with rear brake mounts for either U brakes or possibly V brakes if its more recent.  This shows it had rear brakes when built.

The trackends show its a single speed, so no gears.

The large bottom bracket housing shows it was probably a 1-piece crank, not a 3 piece crank like a nicer bike.

Upshot - it could be any brand, but the odds are its a low-grade big-box-store kids bike.   I do hope you have more of the bits than just the frame, else building it up will be expensive.